# Do duplicate ID values screw up jQuery selectors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I had two divs, both with id="myDiv", would `$("#myDiv").fadeOut();` fade both divs out? Or would it fade only the first/second? Or none at all?

How do I change which one it fades out?

**Note:** I know duplicate id's is against standards but I'm using the fancybox modal popup and it duplicates specified content on your page  for the content of the popup. If anyone knows a way around this (maybe I'm using fancybox wrong) please let me know.

Comment: Yes, but I was hoping if I asked someone else they might be able to give me an explanation as to why only the first one gets faded out.

Comment: Does it duplicate? or "move" the content into your popups position?

Comment: it duplicates it. when I look at the source code via Firebug, I can visibly see the code in there twice. Once where I put it, and once inside the fancybox

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery id selector works only for the first element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114622/jquery-id-selector-works-only-for-the-first-element)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jQuery matches exactly one element when querying for an ID. An array of at most one `Element` object will be returned by `$("#foo").get()`. See the [jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/id) for more information, or try it yourself.

```
$(function() {
    alert($("#foo").length);
});
```

Comment: $("#foo") does not return an array.  It returns an object containing several functions.  $("#foo").get() is an array.

Comment: in fact you can index the jquery object e.g $('.foo')[0]. Does this make it an array ;)

Comment: As redsquare said, you can access elements using subscripts, and jQuery also provides a "length" property. In that sense you can treat it like an array. However, the other array function (like pop, join, etc) are not provided. I updated my answer to include the get function, as Matthew pointed out.

Answer (score 12):

Element IDs are supposed to be unique. Having multiple DIVs of the same ID would be incorrect and unpredictable, and defies the purpose of the ID. If you did this:

```
$('.myDiv').fadeOut();
```

That would fade both of them out, assuming you give them a class of myDiv and unique IDs (or none at all).

Answer (score 7):

"Note: I know duplicate id's is against standards"

Then don't do it.  You have already figured out two problems. It violates standards, and it interferes with jQuery's (and indeed the regular DOM's) selection mechanism.  There will probably be more issues in the future.

Quite possibly, you *are* using fancybox wrong, in which case I hope someone familiar with it helps you. Or worse, if the script itself is flawed, you shouldn't use it.

Comment: so I'm supposed to write my own modal popup then? I know I'm not the only one who uses fancybox. This didn't really answer my question at all...

Comment: I never suggested you write your own modal dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Since $('#myDiv') will only return the first div with that ID, you'll have to find all elements with that ID using this trick:

```
$('[id=myDiv]');
```

So, for your case, to apply the fadeOut to all of those divs:

```
$('[id=myDiv]').fadeOut();
```

And if you want to make sure your page doesn't have this ID twice then you can remove the extra ones by doing this:

```
$('[id=myDiv]:gt(0)').remove();
```

Comment: I think that everyone agrees that having duplicate ids is one of the worst things you can do (hurts little kitties & make sad pandas). Although, this trick helped me fix a little bug in a small utility Web app that I've written. In fact, I have hidden tables that serve as templates (I copy them to generate new ones) and those templates contain Ids because I then use those ids for translating on the client side (yes, I'm having some fun with JavaScript here ^^)

Comment: I find it idiotic that the selectors `$("#myid")` and `$("[id='myid']")` should give different results. No, a page should not have more than one element with a given id, but bugs happen and need to be found. If you already suspect an error like this it is much easier to just enter a query than run a validator. This is like asking the cops for how many people commit suicide in custody and getting the answer that that mustn't happen, so the answer is therefore 0. I guess `$(#myid")` is way faster, but it's still misleading. Maybe a new property `$(#myid").exists` could stand in.

Answer (score 1):

You can also go the route of using find(). find will return all the elements with that ID, and you can limit the scope to a particular parent if needed try something like `$(document).find('#myDiv').fadeOut();`

or

```
$('.parentElement').find('#myDiv').fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem.  Apparently, when you create content on the page from which you wish to open a Fancybox, it creates a mirror div of the original content.  In my instance, the controls were wrapped in a div that fancybox creates named, "fancy_div"

I was able to select the control and get it’s value by using the following format for the selector:

```
$('#fancy_div [id=InputText]').val();
```

your controls may exist elsewhere within the Fancybox.  the best thing to do is look at the viewsource, but it's tricky.

To get to the view source, use the following technique:
Place this tag on your form:
Get value
Open your form, click on the tag to open the alert window.
Make sure your cursor is within the page content (find a control and click).
Right click out of the control and select "view source".
A bunch of divs exist, so look for the div that contains your content.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar problem.  I had a single page that displayed different content through an Ajax load.  There is a button that triggers the server to generate a PDF image.

My original solution was to use a class selector, which worked fine, but caused friction with another developer.  There were so many classes already in the links that using a class as an identifier made the code ugly.  So I used a name attribute:

```
<a name="printButton"....

$('a[name="printButton"]').on('click',function(){....
```

Worked just dandy!