# click handler remains after deleting element and perform its actions multiple times

Tags: jquery, live

I am dynamically adding a custom component with buttons this way

```
function showPopup(){
var comp = '<div id="alert"><input type="button" id="proceed"><input type="button" id="close"></div>';

$('#body').append(comp);

}
```

To these buttons I have handlers like this

```
$('#close').live('click',function(){
$(this).parent().remove();
});

$('#proceed').live('click',function(){
//ajax-call
});
```

Now the issue is when I call the function say n times and close it and when i do a proceed now it does n ajax calls.
Any solution to this ?
Thank you

Comment: Are you executing the handler code snippets each time showPopup() is called?

Comment: I'm guessing it's not actually that way in your real code because it wouldn't work, but you are missing `()` on your `parent` call.

Comment: @Yardboy: no the handlers are not executed on showPopup

Comment: this: "Now the issue is when I call the function say n times and close it and when i do a proceed now it does n ajax calls" confuses me - call the function n times - which function? "and close it" close what, what is "it" I think we need to see the "ajax-call" exactly. And which jQuery version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding multiple elements with the same `id` which is invalid markup. This will be causing problems for jQuery when it comes to delegating the event to the correct element. jQuery matches exactly one element when querying for an ID - see [Does duplicate id's screw up jquery selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053882/does-duplicate-ids-screw-up-jquery-selectors/1053890#1053890)

Also, [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZASuL/) seems to be working for me in Chrome 14.

Comment: but i am deleting the button on close

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell for sure because you don't have the `live` calls in context but I assume that the calls to `live` are within some code that is called multiple times.  If so, this is the problem.  `live` should only be called once for each element.  `live` will then automatically apply to all items created matching the selector.  If it is called multiple times you will attach another handler each time.