# jQuery selector: select a child of a known element

Tags: jquery, find, selector, frame, parent-child

I'm having troubles selecting a specific textarea element with an ID I know.
Worst part of this is that the HTML page I have to work on contains two textarea with this ID. I know this is not right, but I have no control over that part.

So, in that page I have two main elements: `<div id="left_column">` and `<div id="right_column">` which both contains an element `<textarea id="CPR_DESCRIPTION">`

Between the left and right_columns div and their respective `#CPR_DESCRIPTION` child textarea there is a plethora of other elements and they are similar on each side.

I wish to select both these `#CPR_DESCRIPTION` textarea separately (because I have to add the content of the `#left_column`'s `#CPR_DESCRIPTION` into `#right_column`'s one) but all my attempts are failing so far.

I have tried:

```
$('#left_column textarea#CPR_DESCRIPTION');

$('#left_column, textarea#CPR_DESCRIPTION');

$('#left_column').find('textarea#CPR_DESCRIPTION');
```

It's worth noting that I manage to retrieve `#left_column` as a div, but when it comes to retrieving `#CPR_DESCRIPTION`, no success. Also note that `#CPR_DESCRIPTION` is NOT a direct child of `#left_column`.

Here is the relevant part of HTML as asked (prepare your eyes for horrible stuff):

```
<div id="left_column">
  <div id="property">
    <div class="body>
      <div class="inner">
        <iframe id="property">
          <html>
            <body class="dialog">
              <div id="G360Layout">
                <form id="fieldsForm">
                  <div id="mainContainer">
                    <div id="container_2">
                      <div id="fields_container">
                        <div id="container_Description">
                          <div id="component_188">
                            <table>
                              <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                  <td>
                                    <textarea id="CPR_DESCRIPTION" name="CPR_DESCRIPTION">
                                      egeezezez
                                    </textarea>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </body>
          </html>
        </iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So this is the monster I have to deal with, as you can see there are already duplicated IDs and worst part is that `#right_column` is EXACTLY the same.

here is my jQuery:

```
function doOnLoadLayoutDescription() {

alert("inside doOnLoadLayoutDescription");

var leftColumn = $('#left_column');
//alert("leftColumn.length="+leftColumn.length);
//var description = $('textarea#CPR_DESCRIPTION');
//var description = leftColumn.find('textarea#CPR_DESCRIPTION');
var description = $('#left_column').find('textarea[id=CPR_DESCRIPTION]');
alert("description.length="+description.length);
if(description.val()) {

    alert("inside description.val()");

    var text = description.val();

    alert(text);

    var rightColumn = $('#right_column');
    var readOnlyDescription = rightColumn .find('textarea#CPR_DESCRIPTION');
    if (readOnlyDescription.length) {

        alert("inside readOnlyDescription.length");

        readOnlyDescription.val(text);

        alert("switch done");

        }
    }
    alert("ouside doOnLoadLayoutDescription");
}
```

NOTE: I changed the question a bit because I said it was a div but it was a textarea, even if doesn't change much, might be a good idea to rectify this now.

NOTE2: This HTML page is generated from a .jsp page that is part of a Case Management System called Case360 which is not so known. As all the content of the .jsp is generated through a drag-and-drop layout builder, it explains why this HTML is almost impossible to read comfortably.

**EDIT**
I think I found the issue:
The script I gave up there is actually being wrapped up inside the iframe element and thus only searches inside that frame, thus not finding my #left_column element. I have tried putting it outside of the iframe, to gain scope on the whole page, not only the frame but then my form's script which calls the other script won't find it now. I need to get a way to get out of that frame stuff in order to work properly. I am working on that right now.

Any idea guys?

Comment: Your first and third examples should work. You're not getting help here because there must be more to the situation.

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle of the relevant part of your HTML structure + JavaScript and then we could wonder what on earth is happening.

Comment: You may also be encountering a limitation (not a bug) of jQuery, where will only act on a single ID of the same name: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053882/does-duplicate-ids-screw-up-jquery-selectors

Comment: Please post your HTML.

Comment: `.find` will work as seen in this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nf5j4/) As the elements with the same identifier are not at the same level you are ok. Something else is causing this issue. We need the exact **relevant** HTML. Same id elements cause issues if there is more than one in the same selector than it only ever returns the first match.

Comment: by any chance, can you add additional classes to those duplicate id divs? (if so I recommend you to do that) ...or the is html you working with static?... otherwise even if you success to make this work in one browser, it may not work in other (ID is pretty much saying "uniq" on the page )

Comment: adding additional classes is already something I thought I could do but I have time to try to make it work without that so I'll make this option my last hope ;). I'm currently trying to gather a relevant html part that will not overload your eyes. :P

Comment: As I don't know if you guys receive a notification when a question is edited, I'm notifying you here!

Comment: Sadly, I can't produce a jsFiddle as it won't accept any <html> tag in it. When I alert $('#left_column') I get "div#left_column" but when I want to check the size of it, I get 0. And if I try with .children().size() I get 0 as well... Wtf ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to make this work.
So as I explained in my question under EDIT, the main problem was that my script was wrapped in the `<iframe>` element.
This made it easy to select the first `#CPR_DESCRIPTION` textarea using a simple `$('#CPR_DESCRIPTION')`. The remaining problem was to be able to get into the second `<iframe>` to find the second `#CPR_DESCRIPTION`. In order to do that, I miraculously found a function in some dark places of an old project that does the job. I don't understand it much though (yeah I know it's not nice). But here is the code of that function:

```
function getFrameElement(fFrames, sName) {
    var frame = null;
    var retFrameEle = null;
    var i = 0;
    for (i=(fFrames.length-1) ; i > -1 ; i--) {
        var fFrame = fFrames[i];
        if (fFrame.name == sName) {
            retFrameEle = fFrame;
            break;
        }
        if (fFrame.id == sName) {
            retFrameEle = fFrame;
            break;
        }
        retFrameEle = getFrameElement(fFrame.frames, sName);
        if (retFrameEle != null) break;
        }
    return retFrameEle;
}
```

I simply call this function like this: `getFrameElement(top.frames, "doc_content")` with "doc_content" being the `id` and `name` of the frame I'm looking for.

Note that this is written in basic javascript which means I needed to keep on with basic javascript and simply using

```
getFrameElement(top.frames, "doc_content").document.getElementById("CPR_DESCRIPTION");
```

made the trick to find the second `#CPR_DESCRIPTION` textarea.

Thank you for all those who helped :)

Answer (score 2):

Since jQuery may not allow duplicate ID selectors (as it shouldn't), try this:

```
$('#left_column').find('textarea[id=CPR_DESCRIPTION]');
```

Comment: `$('#left_column').find('#CPR_DESCRIPTION')` and `$('#right_column').find('#CPR_DESCRIPTION')` works fine http://jsfiddle.net/nf5j4/ The issue will be if you would just do `$("CPR_DESCRIPTION")` as then jQuery only returns the first one. In the previous 2 examples there is only ever one match as they are in different selectors.

Comment: Take your URL out of code mode so I can click it. I'm feeling very lazy this morning. :-)

Comment: You're almost certainly right (for most cases), but this might be worth trying.

Comment: I have tried this, changing div for textarea but doesn't work either, even if it should.

Comment: I don't see this scenario in your 'I tried' list. Did you use it with the exact syntax as above (updated for your scenario)?

Answer (score 0):

IDs are required to be unique, so just `$("#CPR_DESCRIPTION")` will work just fine.

In the general case, however, you should use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) like so:

```
$(somelement).find(".selector");
```

However if you know the selector for the first element, you can just use a simple descendant selector:

```
$("#someelement .selector") // any level deep
$("#someelement>.selector") // only first-level children
```

Comment: yeah that's what I tried with my first example, this should work. But for some reason it doesn't.

Comment: Well, no. Even if you have duplicate IDs, with the first selector, you narrow the search context to exclude the other element with the same ID, so it should still work.