# jquery not executed with twitter bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am just starting to use Twitter Bootstrap which works pretty fine.

However I am trying to add some custom jquery code.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"/>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $( "#link" ).click(function() {
            alert( "Handler for .click() called." );                
        });
    });
</script>
```

Somehow the JS alert does not get fired.

Any idea what's wrong here?

The related #link tag looks as follows:

```
<p><a id="link" class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details</a></p>
```

Comment: 1.7.2? Did you know it's up to 1.10.2 now?

Comment: Do you have duplicate IDs?

Comment: Does the `link` definitely exist on page load?

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle link of your code

Comment: If you're adding `#link` to the page after the document has loaded, consider using delegation: `$(document).on('click', '#link', function () { });`...

Comment: I like when OP doesn't answer any question...

Comment: I like the invisible answer the best.

Comment: @Andy  display:hidden i guess

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/U2kbF/2/show/ is working fine.

Answer (score 3):

You can't self-close `<script>` tags like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"/>
```

Change it to:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Then make sure you [don't have two elements with the same `link` ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053882/does-duplicate-ids-screw-up-jquery-selectors), that `<a id="link">` [exists on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/jquery-click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements), and perhaps include an `alert` outside the event handler to make sure that block of code is running at all.

Comment: @Ravimallya sorry but where? I cannot see it