# Will the selector $('#myform') return a array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new in javascript and jQuery and I just read a code like `$('#myForm').get(0).submit()`

As far as my understanding, the `myForm` is an id for a `<form>` and it should be an unique id. So why this code use `get(0)` which seem the selector returns an array. Will there be more than one html elements with same id `myForm` ?

Comment: When using the Id there should only be one. Don't worry about the get(0) see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1053890/1071091

Comment: **Any** jQuery selector returns array (actually array-lke object) **regardless** of result number of matches.

Answer (score 1):

jquery always returns an array but you can work with it like an single object.

e.g.:

```
$("#someID").submit();
```

or any other jquery function:

```
$("#someID").html("<h1>test</h1>");
```

you also can get the javascript element with:

```
$("#someID")[0];
```

Comment: jQuery selector returns always an Object. Check it with typeof.

Comment: try this :)

`var x = new Array();`

`typeof(x); // returns object ;)`

Comment: Oh right I forgot that it's more complicated to check in javascript if something is an array since everything is actualy an object. You can check it with this if( Object.prototype.toString.call( x) === '[object Array]' ) {
    alert( 'Array!' );
}

Answer (score 1):

For id selectors, jQuery uses the JavaScript function `document.getElementById()`

What it do is selects a *single* element with the given id attribute.
Jquery returns it wrapped in custom object. From the [devx blog](http://www.devx.com/codemag/Article/40923):

> Selectors return a jQuery object known as the "wrapped set," which is
>   an array-like structure that contains all the selected DOM elements.
>   You can iterate over the wrapped set like an array or access
>   individual elements via the indexer ($(sel)[0] for example). More
>   importantly, you can also apply jQuery functions against all the
>   selected elements.

Answer (score 1):

> *As far as my understanding, the myForm is an id for a `<form>` and it should be an unique id. **So why this code use get(0)** which seem the selector returns an array.*

That is same as this:

```
$('#myForm')[0].submit();
```

The thing to notice is that, jQuery selector gives you a jQuery object and only jQuery methods can be applied on it.

But in your case it seems that you want to trigger the native DOM `submit` event and that only can be applied on dom nodes not on jQuery objects. So, `.get(0)` returns a DOM node and `.submit()` event has been triggered on it. Although that can be simplified in javascript as :

```
document.querySelector('#myForm').submit();
```

or

```
document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
```

---

If you get to the [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) docs:

> **Description:** Retrieve one of the elements matched by the jQuery object. ***The `.get()` method grants access to the DOM nodes underlying each jQuery object***. If the value of index is out of bounds — less than the negative number of elements or equal to or greater than the number of elements — it returns undefined.

Answer (score 1):

It is jquery selector returns an array. If DOM is correct, which means id is unique for each element, then you sure can use

```
   $('#form_id').submit()
```

instead of

```
   $('#form_id').get(0).submit()
```

However, $('#form_id') returns an jquery object while $('#form_id').get(0) returns a DOM element. jquery object can use jquery functions.

```
  $('#id')//jquery object array
  $('#id')[0]//first element of this array
  $('#id').get(0)//first element of this array, DOM element
  $('#id').eq(0)//first element of this array, jquery object
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the documentation: https://api.jquery.com/submit/ you can exec submit function directly to the form object:

```
$('#myForm').submit();
```

Furthermore, as you can read here https://api.jquery.com/get/

> Each jQuery object also masquerades as an array