# jquery input tags not working in modal popup

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add input tags in my modal popup using jQuery tagsInput. It working fine on a single page but not working in the modal. How can I add tagsInput in my modal popup?

I have followed these codes:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Jquery - input tags</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-tagsinput/1.3.6/jquery.tagsinput.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-tagsinput/1.3.6/jquery.tagsinput.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="background: #337AB7">


<div style="width: 500px; margin: 0px auto;">
    <h2 style="font-family:cursive;">Jquery - input tags plugin example</h2>
    <input name="tags" id="input-tags" style="width:500px !important" />
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <input name="tags" id="input-tags" style="width:500px !important" />
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#input-tags').tagsInput();
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The issue isn't with the modal. It's with the duplicate IDs you've assigned. IDs _must be unique_ or they don't identify anything. jQuery only acts on the first one and it's invalid HTML.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053882/does-duplicate-ids-screw-up-jquery-selectors

Answer (score 1):

Please put this line after open the model

```
$('#input-tags').tagsInput();
```

**For example:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="openModal">Open Modal</button>
<script>
    $('#openModal').on('click', function() {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        $('#input-tags').tagsInput();
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified the `type` for input tag.

```
<input type="text" class="input" name="tags" id="input-tags" style="width:500px !important" />
```

Also you have used same `IDs` please use class name selector in jquery also add class names on the inputs.

```
$('.input').tagsInput();
```